# Recursive call not in tail position

Tags: scala

Say I define the following function:

```
final def myFunc[T](list: List[T]): List[T] = list match {
        case h :: t =>
            h :: myFunc(t)
        case _ =>
            Nil
    }
```

When I add a tailrec annotation the compiler gives me the following error:

> could not optimize @tailrec annotated method myFunc: it contains a
>   recursive call not in tail position:  ^Nil.

I am confused as to how the declaration of Nil can be a recursive call?

Comment: It's not the `Nil` it's the `::`, it means that you still have to concatenate the partial results to `h` for each call in the stack, that's why this method is not tail recursive. As test, try `case h :: t => myFunc(t)` with the tailrec annotation on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is not with the `Nil` but with `h :: myFunc(t)` because `myFunc(t)` is not the last call. The last call is to the operator `::` on the result of `myFunc(t)`. That is why the function is not tail recursive.

Comment: Guess it was the compiler message that was misleading.

Comment: unrelated but possibly useful info: `h :: myFunc(t)` is the same as `myFunc(t).::(h)` due to Scala operator associativity rules. When you rewrite it like that, it's more obvious that the recursive call is not in a tail position. The operator associativity rules in Scala are luckily quite simple: if the operator ends with `:` character, it is right-associative, otherwise left-associative. So one needs to pay extra attention to `#::` or `::` or `+:` etc.